# returning a class constructor string in another class in java

Tags: java

I have a class loan which has a constructor that set a string totalpaymentamt

I also have another class loan test which has the main method and am using it to output the string

I have done

```
public class Loan {
    public Loan() {
        String totalpaymentamt = "\t toString() results" + this.toString(this.getDuration(),
            this.getInterestRate(),
            this.gettotalAmount()) + "  \n \t getNumberOfYears() results:" + this.getDuration() + " getInterestRate() results:" + this.getInterestRate() + "  getTotalAmount() results:" + this.gettotalAmount() + " getMonthlyPayment:" + this.getMonthlyPayment(this.getDuration(),
            this.getInterestRate(),
            this.gettotalAmount());
    }
}
```

The other class is

```
public Loan(int duration, double interestRate, double totalAmount) {
     this.totalpaymentamt = "\t toString() results" + this.toString(duration, interestRate, totalAmount)

     + "  \n \t getNumberOfYears() results:" + duration
         + " getInterestRate() results:" + interestRate + "  getTotalAmount() results:" + totalAmount + " getMonthlyPayment:" + this.getMonthlyPayment(duration, interestRate, totalAmount);

}
```

This doesnt return anything. I understand a constructor has no return statement, How can i return the results o the loan constructor to the Testloan class main method

Comment: Have a formal toString method in the class and call that

Comment: You need to Override Object class' toString() method to make that TestLoan main method work

Comment: Could always use a getter() method and make your String a global private String. Im not sure if this is the best option though.

Comment: @MichaelPickett It doesn't necessarily need to be a private variable. The getter could just return that string directly.

Comment: @4castle You are right. But it would neex to be a global if the getter is going to return it. Although, if he made it public he could just call `new Loan().totalpaymentamt`. But i figured private would be better coding wise.

Comment: Like all above said `toString()` is designed for this purpose and either way if you want to access these statements in other class by making use of constructor, means you are creating object for that class and its not bad if you'll use that object for calling something which otherwise seems impossible

Comment: and one more thing like you creating your own customized `toString()`, return `String` from it as you are not overriding **default** toString method,  use `StringBuffer/Builder`. and please check the proper use of `toString()` a simple google search will solve that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constructor doesn't return anything.

Also, In your TestLoan class, you're extending the Loan class, which you don't need to do.

If you change the loan class constructor to something like this:

```
public class Loan {
    private String totalpaymentamt;

    public Loan() {

        this.totalpaymentamt = "\t toString() results"
                + this.toString(this.getDuration(),
                        this.getInterestRate(),
                        this.gettotalAmount())
                + "  \n \t getNumberOfYears() results:"
                + this.getDuration()
                + " getInterestRate() results:"
                + this.getInterestRate()
                + "  getTotalAmount() results:"
                + this.gettotalAmount()
                + " getMonthlyPayment:"
                + this.getMonthlyPayment(this.getDuration(),
                        this.getInterestRate(),
                        this.gettotalAmount());

    }


    public String getTotalPaymentAmount() {
        return this.totalpaymentamt;
    }
}
```

And then, in TestLoan, you can do:

```
Loan loan = new Loan();
System.out.println("First Loan \n " + loan.getTotalPaymentAmount());
```

Comment: Sorry but i had orgot to insert that there is another constructor taking parameters